# frozen dataclass in def __init__ and iteration on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-attrs

I want to use a frozen class as a structure as I don't want to use any mutable objects in my code. But also I need to iterate on `my_data`. How can I make this work?

SideNote: dict is not an option

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

data = {'demo1': "description for demo 1", "demo2": 'description for demo 2'}


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class SomeDataclass:
    name: str
    description: str


class ParserClass:
    def __init__(self, some_data_class: SomeDataclass) -> None:
        self.my_data = some_data_class

    def parsing_method(self, demo_data) -> None:
        for data, description in demo_data.items():
            self.my_data(name=data, description=description)

test = ParserClass(SomeDataclass)
test.parsing_method(data)
for my_date in test.my_data:
    print(my_date.name, my_date.description)
```

of course, i'm getting an error

```
for my_date in test.my_data:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your classes being dataclasses - why do you expect to be able to iterate over a type? You're not even assigning anything in `parsing_method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean to make a collection of instances?

```py
from attrs import frozen

data = {'demo1': "description for demo 1", "demo2": 'description for demo 2'}

@frozen(kw_only=True)
class SomeDataclass:
    name: str
    description: str

class ParserClass:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.my_data = []

    def parsing_method(self, demo_data) -> None:
        for data, description in demo_data.items():
            self.my_data.append(SomeDataclass(name=data, description=description))

test = ParserClass()
test.parsing_method(data)
for my_date in test.my_data:
    print(my_date.name, my_date.description)
```

Here `ParserClass` has a `list` at `self.my_data` and `parsing_method()` appends new instances of `SomeDataclass` to it.